# How to stop replication in SQL Server 2012 using code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-replication

I want to add column in a table but this message appears:

> 'Students' table
>   - Unable to modify table.   The data definition language (DDL) command cannot be executed at the Subscriber. DDL commands can only be
>   executed at the Publisher. In a republishing hierarchy, DDL commands
>   can only be executed at the root Publisher, not at any of the
>   republishing Subscribers. The schema change failed during execution of
>   an internal replication procedure. For corrective action, see the
>   other error messages that accompany this error message. The
>   transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: You can execute the statement to add a column at the Publisher, you don't need to stop the replication per se.

Comment: What's your overall goal here? Is it to have an actual different schema at the subscriber than the publisher?

Comment: I was found solution ,execute the procedure sp_removereplication'DatabaseName'